# Minimum length in password for django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am making a form in Django and I am using the "form.is_valid" to get all the error. Everything works except the minimum value for the password. I have following code for my form:

```
class RegisterationForm (forms.Form):

first_name = forms.CharField(initial ='' ,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),max_length = 20)
last_name = forms.CharField(initial ='' ,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),max_length = 20)
username = forms.CharField(initial ='' ,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),min_length = 5,max_length = 20)
email = forms.EmailField(initial ='' ,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))


def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegisterationForm, self).clean()
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']

    if password and password != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("passwords do not match")

    return self.cleaned_data

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']

    return username

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']


    return email

def clean_password(self):
    password= self.cleaned_data['password']

    if len(password) < 6:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your password should be at least 6 Characters")

    return password
```

but here when I enter a password less than 6 characters, instead of getting a validation error I get an error from Django. The error is a key error which is caused because the cleaned_data dictionary does not contain the password when it's longer than 6 chars. **I also used the min_length feature in form definition as well and the same thing happened**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `password` or `password2` is not valid, then they will not be in `cleaned_data`. You need to change your `clean` method to handle this. For example:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegisterationForm, self).clean()
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

    if password and password2 and password != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("passwords do not match")
```

You could specify `min_length` in your `password` field. Then Django will validate the length for you, and you can remove your custom `clean` method.

```
password = forms.CharField(min_length=6, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
```

Finally, your `clean_username` and `clean_email` methods are not doing anything so you can simplify your form by removing them.

Comment: Yes it makes sense